# Removing the blue background for images in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm using images in a listview to show the state of entries.
These images show with a blue background:

[image: Blue Background]

It's not part of the image and not as wide as the cell. I've tried changing the listviewitems' back- and forecolor, which didn't change anything.

The images come from a SmallImageList:

```cs
Bitmap bmpOK = Properties.Resources.GlobalOK;
bmpOK.MakeTransparent(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0, 255));
Bitmap bmpNOK = Properties.Resources.GlobalNotOK;
bmpNOK.MakeTransparent(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0, 255));
imglist.ImageSize = new Size(16, 16);

imglist.Images.Add(bmpOK);
imglist.Images.Add(bmpNOK);

listview.SmallImageList = imglist;
```

And are later added by using the ImageIndex, such as:

```
listviewitem.ImageIndex = 1;
```

How do I get rid of the blue background?

Comment: Are you sure the backgrounds of these images are transparent to begin with?

Comment: The background of the images are pink, which is why I turn them transparent. The images themselves are square, the blue does not come from the images. I tried turning it transparent just to be sure, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Could the blues be the selection color?

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out but idk how to change the selection color. Either way, the items are not selected.

Comment: Did you set a TransparencyKey anywhere? - The normal selection color is a system option based on the user's theme. You can owner-draw the ListView to override it. Do you? - Also: do you think they are in the background or maybe to the left of the field?

Comment: I don't override the listview drawing and I don't set a TransparencyKey. To more precisely describe the blue color: It is right below the image and to the left of it, filling whatever is left of the cell there. However, the cell expands to the right where it is NOT colored in blue.

Comment: Did you set `ColorDepth = Depth32Bit` in your ImageList? Do these Bitmap actually have the same exact background Color on both sides (`MakeTransparent` is quite strict)? Did you try to use Bitmaps that are actually transparent (PNG or Icon - well, same thing with GDI+)?

Comment: Tried ColorDepth. Yes, the bitmaps background color is exactly the same, otherwise there'd be pink leftovers, not blue ones (plus the blue is outside). I've tried an icon with actual transparency, same issue. I don't think the problem lies within the image itself (not the file, anyway, miiiiiight be the image object) since the image itself is fine, the blue is to the bottom and to the left of the image.

Comment: `ColorDepth = Depth32Bit` must be set **before** you add the Images, i.e., when the ImageList creates it's own copies. when I said *other Bitmaps*, I meant Bitmap that are transparent without calling `MakeTransparent` with a specific Color.

Comment: I had set it after, but if I set it before it doesn't solve the issue, either.

Comment: Sure. Make a new Form, add a ListBox and an ImageList. Set `ImageList.ColorDepth = Depth32Bit`. Load some really transparent Images into the ImagelList. Set the ImageList as the `SmallImageList` property of your ListView, add some Items to it, don't set the BackColor of the Items to anything, or set `Color.Transparent`...

Comment: Images are not the cause. I've just tested it without images and I get a blue bar.

Comment: Then your Items have a background Color set. Unless you're referring to the standard Selection bar that the Control draws when you select an Item (but that draws with a semi-transparent color above the Images). Maybe post an animation that describes the problem. Set the ListView in both `Details`  and `List` View.